# Spring Batch Reading AWS S3 -stepExecutionContext is null

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to read files from AWS s3 using spring batch but the file name becomes null in stepExecutionContext. Same code was working when i read the files from the windows mount but when we migrate the code and reading it from S3 it is becoming null.

```java
    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public CustomMultiResourcePartitioner partitioner() {
        CustomMultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new CustomMultiResourcePartitioner();
        Set<String > filesToProcess= fileRepository.findAllFilesByFileState("NEW");
        List<Resource> resourceList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(String file:filesToProcess) {
            Resource resource = getS3Resource(file);
            resourceList.add(resource);
            log.info("resourceList Size"+resourceList.size());
        }
        if(resourceList.size()>0 && resourceList.toArray()!=null) {
            resources = resourceList.stream().toArray(Resource[]::new);
            ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
            executionContext.put("FILE_NAME",filesToProcess);
        }
        else
        {
            resources = new Resource[0];
        }
        partitioner.setResources(resources);
        return partitioner;
    }
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<RosterInput> itemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[fileName]}") String filename) throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException {
        FlatFileItemReader<RosterInput> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<RosterInput>();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        tokenizer.setStrict(false);
        Resource resource =getS3Resource(filename);
}
```

Comment: Without sharing the code of `getS3Resource(file)`, we can't really help. Please make sure you are able to get a `Resource` from s3 before using it in your Spring Batch job.

Comment: Good to see you solved your issue. Please do not add code in comments, it is not readable. You can add an answer and show how you fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was using `ByteArrayResource` in my `getS3Resource()` method it was causing the file name to null. After modifying the code to use below the problem is solved.

```java
public class FileNameAwareByteArrayResource extends ByteArrayResource {

    private String fileName;

    public FileNameAwareByteArrayResource(String fileName, byte[] byteArray) {
        super(byteArray);
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFilename() {
        return fileName;
    }
}
```